# How would you check for undefined property in ejs for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, ejs

What is the best way to check for an undefined property in an ejs template?

(I'm using the [node.js package](http://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) by TJ Holowaychuk)

Example:

```
var tpl = '<% if (foo) { %>foo defined<% } else { %>foo undefined<% } %>';
console.log(ejs.render(tpl, { locals: { bar: "baz" } }));
```

I'd expect this to render "foo undefined". It does throw an *foo undefined* error instead.

I know that this is not supposed to be an issue, since this is expected behavior [in the tests](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/blob/master/test/ejs.test.js#L246). Is there an easy way to avoid this?

The only solution I found is using the `hasOwnProperty` method.

```
var tpl = '<% if (hasOwnProperty("foo")) { %>foo defined<% } else { %>foo undefined<% } %>';
console.log(ejs.render(tpl, { locals: { bar: "baz"} }));
```

This doesn't throw any errors.

Is there a better way to keep the template clean? Or why does it throw this error?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Another way to test for a property is to reference it indirectly via the `locals` object. Using your example:

```
var tpl = '<% if(locals.foo){ %>foo defined<% }else{ %>foo undefined<% } %>';
console.log(ejs.render(tpl, { locals: { bar: "baz"} }));
```

Comment: Just what I needed, but wtf, why do you have to do this?! :)

Comment: Not sure without checking the source, but I suspect that the template engine doesn't bother to scope variables for undefined values.

Answer (score 34):

I would use `typeof`, as in `if (typeof foo == 'undefined')`. I use the `typeof` operator with the string "undefined", whereas some people might do a direct comparison with the `undefined` global variable. I prefer this method because it is protected against some terrorist JS library developer changing the value of the global variable, leaving your code broken.

This could also be expressed as a ternary, which some view as "cleaner" due to the absence of curlies:

```
var tpl = '<% (typeof foo != "undefined" ? %>foo defined<% : %>foo undefined<% ) %>';
```

Comment: This works and maybe it's the formally correct one. But I personally don't like it, since it's too long for my templates.

Comment: Note that this is the only method that will work with client side EJS templates. The other methods rely on checking the `res` object which will not exist with client side templates.

Answer (score 16):

Simplest, and cleanest in my opinion:

`<%= (!!locals.foo)?foo:'' %>`

Comment: locals seems to have moved to the res object in later ejs versions.

Comment: Can confirm that <%= (locals.title) ? title : "Default Title" %> works

Answer (score 3):

Earlier version of EJS supports only `locals`
But
Now in the latest versions of EJS support `res.locals`

Sample with ternary operator -

```
<%= (res.locals.foo)?"foo":"" %>
```

Sample with if-else -

```
<% if (res.locals.urvariable) { %>
   <h1><%= urvariable.value1 %></h1> 
<% } else { %> 
   <h1><%= urvariable.value2 %></h1> 
<% } %>
```