# EJS and Node, EJS throws an error if passed in object does not exist?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

I am trying to pass a message object to a template using ejs.  My route code is as follows:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs', {message: 'A message'});
});
```

In my ejs (index.ejs) file, I have:

```
    <% if (message) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    <% } %>
```

But when I do not pass an object at all (not just `message: ""`) it returns the following error:

```
ReferenceError: /Users/Documents/node/views/index.ejs:13
    11| <body>
    12|     <div class="container">
 >> 13|         <% if (message) { %>
    14|             <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    15|         <% } %>
    16|         <div class="jumbotron text-center">

message is not defined
```

Similarly, if I try `if(message.length > 0)` but that just gives me the same error.  I thought the whole point of an `if` statement would be that the if `message` doesn't exist, it just skips.  How can I just make ejs render nothing if the message object is not passed or do I have to pass an empty `message` obect each time?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand. Passing no object results in that error.  I would prefer to not have to pass an object with an empty string each time...

Comment: You could try using ```locals.message```, as it's shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289916/how-would-you-check-for-undefined-property-in-ejs-for-node-js

Answer (score 5):

Explicitly check whether or not `message` is defined. This fixes it:

```
<% if (typeof message !== 'undefined' && message.length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```