# EJS failing to render template

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I'm trying to render a template which includes this block of code:

```
<% if(type === 'Not Within Specifications'){ %>
           <% if(Length !== undefined) { %><h5>Length: <%= Length %> </h5> <% } %>
           <% if(Width !== undefined) { %><h5>Width: <%= Width %> </h5> <% } %>
           <% if(thickness !== undefined) { %><h5>Thickness: <%= thickness %> </h5> <% } %>
 <% } %>
```

However when the template attempts to render, it throws and error that a variable is "undefined" if one of the above variables is in fact undefined.

The point of the if statements catching undefined variables was to eliminate this error from happening, however it seems that the error is still being thrown even when i'm checking to see if the variable is undefined. Does anyone know why this might be? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `typeof`:

```
<% if(type === 'Not Within Specifications'){ %>
           <% if(typeof Length !== 'undefined') { %><h5>Length: <%= Length %> </h5> <% } %>
           <% if(typeof Width !== 'undefined') { %><h5>Width: <%= Width %> </h5> <% } %>
           <% if(typeof thickness !== 'undefined') { %><h5>Thickness: <%= thickness %> </h5> <% } %>
 <% } %>
```

Also, see this related question: [How would you check for undefined property in ejs for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289916/how-would-you-check-for-undefined-property-in-ejs-for-node-js)

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the link. Don't know how I missed that article.