# Handle `<property> is not defined` error in ejs

Tags: node.js, ejs

I would like ejs not to throw an error when rendering a template using a property which does not exist in the object being passed. Is there a way ejs to just display blank value, empty string, null or undefined for the missing property instead of throwing an error and crashing?

```
let template = 'Name: <%= name %>, Age: <%= age %>';
let result = ejs.render(template, { name: "John" });
```

Currently I get this error on `ejs.render` method:

```
ReferenceError: ejs:1
  >> 1| Name: <%= name %>,Age: <%= age %>
  age is not defined
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you check for undefined property in ejs for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289916/how-would-you-check-for-undefined-property-in-ejs-for-node-js)

Comment: I know i can use the <%= typeof age!='undefined' ? age : 'undefined' %> syntax, but is there a prettier way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that you could handle this.

1. Use nested object properties

```js
    var ejs = require('ejs');
    
    let template = `Name: <%= user.name %> Age: <%= user.age %>`;
    let result = ejs.render(template, { user: { name: "John" }});
    console.log(result)
```

Result:

```
Name: John Age:
```

2. Better yet, use an if statement to exclude empty props. Here I check if the `user.age` is a number.  You can also use `typeof user.age != 'undefined'`

```js
var ejs = require('ejs');

let template = `Name: <%= user.name %> <% if(typeof user.age === "number") { %>Age: <%= user.age %><% } %>`;
let result = ejs.render(template, { user: { name: "John" }});
console.log(result)
```

Result:

```
Name: John
```

No matter what, if a variable is undefined, Node will throw an error.  Using object properties is a bit more forgiving.

If you're dealing with deeply nested objects that may or may not exist, I might suggest using [Lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get). If your property's parent object is undefined, it will handle the issue.  for example if your property is `userdata.personalInfo.details.age` you can use `_.get(userData, ['personalInfo','details','age'], false)` - if `userData.personalinfo` is undefined the function will return `false`.

Comment: the key is <%=foo%>

Answer (score -1):

With newer javascript you might be able to do something like

```
var ejs = require('ejs');
var tpl = `
    <% const {foo,bar} = locals %>
    <%=bar%><%=foo%>
  `;
console.log(ejs.render(tpl, { locals: { bar: "baz",} }));
```